# Dynamic Buttons with Textview in Constraint Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

Currently I am working (learning to use) with ConstraintLayout. Now I created a simple layout with 3 Buttons each line under each button I put a textview, currently I manually am adding the Buttons, but my question is how to dynamically create this layout from a json object or an Array.

The layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="utdevelopments.com.dickelippensoundboard.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.527"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1" />
```

The Layout Looks something like this:

```
|Button|     |Button|     |Button|
|Textview|   |Textview|   |Textview|
|Button|    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it's strictly ConstraintLayout's issue. If you want to create a number of views from certain amount of data — just use **RecyclerView** where your ViewHolder would be layout with Button and pass your array of data in the adapter; that's how you can have dynamically populated «list» of views that you can position and manage any way you want.

If you just starting with Android getting your head around recyclerview and adapters might feel difficult — but payoff is incredible. You would need to be able to work with them in probably all the projects you'd work on.

Comment: could you give me an example of how that would Look like?